# Idiomatic way to conditionally pass parameters to a command in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I need to pass specific options to a program based on the value of the variable `$BAD_SCENARIO`, which is more or less a flag (1 or 0 or empty). I came up with

```bash
program $([ "$BAD_SCENARIO" = "1" ] && echo "--emergency-cleanup" || echo "--normal-cleanup") \
        $([ "$BAD_SCENARIO" = "1" ] && echo "--notify-admin" || echo "")
```

which seems pretty verbose. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: I'd imagine you could use a bash array to compose your arguments, and then pass them.

Comment: At least for the example, I'd just use a regular if statement: `if [ "$BAD_SCENARIO" = "1" ]; then program --emergency-cleanup --notify-admin; else program --normal-cleanup; fi`

Comment: General solution: Create an array for holding **all** arguments of your program. Populate your array, depending on the control variable(s) (`BAD_SCENARIO`). Use the array for passing the arguments to your program.

Comment: `[ test ] && command 1 || command 2` is not a substitute for `if [ test ]; then command 1 else command 2; fi` Why? `[ test ]` can be true and `command 1` fail and you still execute `command 2`.

Answer (score 3):

Use bash arrays. Use `if`.

```
args=()
if [ "$BAD_SCENARIO" = "1" ]; then
   args+=(--emergency-cleanup --notify-admin)
else
   args+=(--normal-cleanup)
fi
program "${args[@]}"
```